# I am mindboggled. Insertion Sort (basic sort, i know) algorithm is doing something I can't explain

Tags: java, insertion-sort

Ok, hear me out. Here is my code for insertion sort.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            T curr = arr[i];
            int i2 = i - 1;
            // if (i2 == -1) {
            //     System.out.println("yes");
            //     break;
            // } 
            while (i2 >= 0 && comparator.compare(arr[i2], curr) > 0) {
                arr[i2 + 1] = arr[i2];
                i2--;
            }
            arr[i2 + 1] = curr;
        }
```

So, as of right now, I have

```
if (i2 == -1) {
    sout("yes");
    break;
}
```

because I wanted to skip the iteration where i2 will obviously be equal to -1 and thus not have a single effect on the array because the first iteration does nothing and keeps the first element in the 0 position of the array because that is exactly how insertion sort works.

Now, I'm not exactly sure what's going on, because, as this aforementioned if statement is commented out, the algorithm works exactly as expected. **BUT**, when I un comment it, the algorithm fails.

What I don't understand is how commenting it out, or not including this if statement at all, leads to a failing algorithm, because no matter what, when i2 == -1, there is literally, as far as I can tell, no effect on the algorithm, since, when i2 is -1, and the if statement described is omitted, the while loop does not execute, and the arr[i2 + 1] = curr statement DOES execute, but it will just keep the first element in its place, EXACTLY how the presence of the if statement keeps the first element in its place because it breaks the loop and does not alter a single thing.

I'm not sure if I'm absolutely insane and missing something inexplicably clear to a sane person, but I literally see not a single way that the omission or inclusion of the if statement described changes anything about the code, especially since i2 will only be -1 on the first iteration of the for loop.

Thank you very much.

Comment: When you say “the algorithm fails,” what specifically is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `break` with `continue`.

Because, at the first iteration, it will always be `-1` and it will break the for loop, which means there are no further iterations.

`continue` is the right weapon.

```
if (i2 == -1) {
    sout("yes");
    continue;
}
```

The above code will skip the 1st iteration, while your code will terminate the for loop.

But, there is no need of this `if` block because you are already filtering out 1st iteration in the condition of `while` loop.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly right, using continue makes the algorithm work as expected. I appreciate it, I don't know why I thought break would continue (funny how I even use the word continue when I explain what I was thinking). It makes 100% sense now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user16320675 Yea, that makes no sense. Actually, I didn't try to understand what is happening in the code, but since SeriousCoder7 said the code is working fine when he comments if block so I thought that line is an essential part of the code, but I realized after reading your comment, Thanks! Updating the answer.